# Building a Manipulate and an ArrayList with JLink

Tags: java

I'm wondering if it's possible to put [this code](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/229641/incorrect-number-or-type-of-arguments-when-using-contains/229644#229644) inside a Manipulate. I tried just like this and got the results in the message box:
[image]

Then when I selected a diferent word from the PopMenu I got this:
[image]

Thought the problem was the `...Print[...]` instructions so tried to build an arraylist like this but totaly failed, there's no result...

```
Needs["JLink`"]

Scanner[archivo_String, palabra_String] :=
 JavaBlock@
  Module[{entrada, linea, numlinea, contiene, ruta, lista, renglon, 
    nop}, numlinea = 1; linea = ""; contiene = False;
   InstallJava[];
   ruta = JavaNew["java.io.File", archivo];
   entrada = JavaNew["java.util.Scanner", ruta];
   lista = JavaNew["java.util.ArrayList"];
   (*Print["File: " <> ruta@getName[]];
   Print["Word:" <> palabra];*)
   While[entrada@hasNext[], linea = entrada@nextLine[]; 
    If[JavaNew["java.lang.String", linea]@
      contains[MakeJavaObject@palabra], 
     renglon = 
      JavaNew["java.lang.String", 
       "Line " <> ToString[numlinea ] <> ": " <> ToString[linea]];
     contiene = True;
     lista@add[renglon];
     JavaObjectToExpression[lista]];
    numlinea++];
   If[! contiene, 
    nop = JavaNew["java.lang.String", 
      ToString[palabra] <> " no se ha encontrado"];
    lista@add[nop];
    JavaObjectToExpression[lista]]]
```

Don't know exactly how to do it, I'd appreciate your help.

Comment: Without having looked too closely at your `Scanner`, the question in the title is answered with something like `list = JavaNew["java.util.ArrayList"];
list@add[MakeJavaObject@1];
list@add[MakeJavaObject@"bob"];
list@add[MakeJavaObject@{"alice"}];
JavaObjectToExpression@list`

Comment: Your `Scanner` function doesn't return anything if it finds `! contiene` to be `False` - your last `If` doesn't have a third argument (the `Else` part).  I also don't understand why you have a call to `JavaObjectToExpression` before the `numlinea++` line when you aren't returning it at that point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has nothing to do with `Manipulate` or `Print`.  Look at the result of `Scanner[file, "issue"]` and you will see that it is `Null`.

Look at your code, the `Scanner` function ends in a statement like this

```
If[! contiene, <do some stuff>]
```

You don't have a third argument for the `If`.  And for any word contained in the file, `contiene` is `True` and so you are evaluating `If[False, <code that is never reached]`

Try this:

```
Scanner[archivo_String, palabra_String] := JavaBlock[
    Module[
        {entrada, linea, numlinea, contiene, ruta, lista, renglon, nop},
        numlinea = 1;
        linea = "";
        contiene = False;
        InstallJava[];
        ruta = JavaNew["java.io.File", archivo];
        entrada = JavaNew["java.util.Scanner", ruta];
        lista = JavaNew @ "java.util.ArrayList";
        While[entrada @ hasNext[],
            linea = MakeJavaObject @ entrada @ nextLine[];
            If[linea @ contains @ palabra,
                renglon = MakeJavaObject @ StringJoin["Line ", ToString @ numlinea, ": ", JavaObjectToExpression @ linea];
                contiene = True;
                lista @ add @ renglon;
                JavaObjectToExpression @ lista
            ];
            ++numlinea
        ];
        If[!contiene,
            lista @ add @ MakeJavaObject @ StringJoin[palabra, " no se ha encontrado"]
        ];
        Column @ JavaObjectToExpression @ lista
    ]
]
```

Comment: Thank's. Tried and got a message about incorrect number or type in `@contains` , ` `If[linea@contains@MakeJavaObject@palabra...` fixed it.